# How to retrieve an Array instead of ArrayData from a Compute Function with RecordBatches in Apache Arrow

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

I'm trying to extract an Array out of a Datum after a Compute Operation.

```
ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(rbatch, ipc_reader->Read(i));
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> numbers_array_a = rbatch->column(2);
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> numbers_array_b = rbatch->column(3);

// Get element-wise sum of both columns A and B in our Table. Note that here we use
// CallFunction(), which takes the name of the function as the first argument.
ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(my_datum, arrow::compute::CallFunction(
                                            "add", {numbers_array_a,
                                                    numbers_array_b}));
```

The Datum now holds an Int64 Array

```
std::cout << "Datum kind: " << my_datum.ToString()
              << " content type: " << my_datum.type()->ToString() << std::endl;

>> Datum kind: Array content type: int64
```

When I now try to print the Array

`std::cout << my_datum.array()->ToString()<< std::end;`

I get this Error

`class "arrow::ArrayData" has no member "ToString"`

The Array class has a ToString() function, but as fas as I know I can't convert ArrayData into an Array.

I tried to convert the ArrayData into an Array, I tried to initialize an Array with the ArrayData and I tried to access the values from the ArrayData all without success.
I tried to initialize a RecordBatch with ArrayData.

I also tried to look for alternatives to retrieve the Array from the Datum but also without success.

How can I print or even access the Array inside the Datum?

Comment: There's no such function in c++, what's unclear about the error message?? Neither raw arrays,  `std::array` or `std::vector` support such functionality, you have to roll your own.

Comment: I have absolutely zero experience with arrow or anything similar, but a quick look at the source code comes up with the `GetValues()`/`GetValuesSafe()` functions, which sound like they allow you to access the array's internal data. These do not appear to be externally documented, unless I am simply looking in the wrong place. I believe `ArrayData`s `length` member is public (and even `buffers`), if you need it. Again, take all of this with a grain of salt, this are just my immediate takeaways from the code.

Comment: `sharedPtr.memberName` refers to `memberName` of the shared pointer, not to the element contained within. Use `sharedPtr->memberName` to refer to a member of the element contained in the shared pointer (or alternatively `(*sharedPtr).memberName`). Not sure about the conversion part...

Comment: To add on to my previous comment; assuming the above functions/members are actually undocumented, and I didn't just miss a docs file or something, I wouldn't depend on them to work the same or even exist in future versions of the software, even if they are public.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, but arrow::Array and arrow::ChunkedArray have this functionality, I would like to build my own, but I cant access the data from arrow::ArrayData in any way.

Comment: @the4naves GetValues(int i) as well as the Overload GetValues(int i, int64_t absolute_offset) and also the "Safe" version doesn't accept an int parameter: 

no instance of overloaded function "arrow::ArrayData::GetValues" matches the argument listC/C++(304)
example.cc(149, 23): argument types are: (int).

buffers[int i] just returns Segmentation Faults or gibberish depending on i

Comment: @fabian Thanks! I changed the Code and the corresponding Error, sadly that didn't change much.

Comment: I'm currently looking at https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/main/cpp/src/arrow/array/data.h#L213, which definitely appears to show a public overload that takes an int, do the headers you're using not?

Comment: On a side note, the implementation of functions like `GetNullCount()` seems to suggest that the only buffer index you'd want to use would be `0`. If `GetValues()` does anything close to what I'm assuming, you'd probably call it once with index `0`, then increment the returned pointer to read out the values.

Comment: Also just to make sure, are you providing a template parameter to `GetValues()`? If so and it still isn't working, you could try `reinterpret_cast<const T*>(buffers[0]->data()) + offset + i`. I assume `T` should be the type of data in the array, `buffers` and `offset` are members of `ArrayData`, and `i` is your loop index, incrementing up to `ArrayData.length-1`.

Comment: Looking a little further, the buffer index used appears to depend on `ArrayData.type`. You can at least check if `buffer[0]` is valid by comparing it to `nullptr`, but if the data is held in a different buffer index it might be in a different format. Even if my above idea works, I'd definitely consider it a hack, and if not, I think my lack of experience in arrow would prevent me from giving any more potentially useful help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the `arrow::Datum::make_array` function:

```
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> result_array = my_datum.make_array();
```